# How can I run a particular powershell command successfully without freezing?

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I'm running a command from the PSWindowsUpdate module on a Windows 2012 server that will show a list of updates that were installed on the server. It's called `Get-WUHistory`. When I ran it on a 2019 server, it worked fine. I did the same thing on a 2012 server. It did showed the list of updates installed but, for some reason, it's as if the command was running forever. It didn't even show this line `PS C:\Windows\System32>` as it should. So, I closed out of Powershell, opened it again and it was back to its normal state.

For a command like `Get-WUHistory`, how should I be able to run that command without having it freeze or take a long time before it finishes?
Is there any way to fix this so it won't have to freeze like that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug with `Get-WUHistory` where it will loop infinitely unless you specify `-Last` like:

```sh
Get-WUHistory -Last 100
```